# Sharepoint hubsite theme background image not pushing out to associated sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection, modern-experience, modern-pages, hub-site

I have created a hubsite with powershell called internalHub. 
In the internalHub i have a orange/black theme with a background image.

[image: InternalHub with working background image]

Next step is to create a regular communication site called TestSiteCollection and associate it with the Internal Hubsite as follow

[image: association with between Internal hub and testsitecollection]

The theme with orange/black on TestSiteCollection seems to be working but the background image on TestSiteCollection isn't there.

[image]

The only "Error" that i have got from SharePoint is the error that comes when i press save. But this error message doesn't reflect this problem i have or is it some related error?
If i debug the page there is no errors about background image. If there was an url miss match i should see 404 in the console but there is none.

[image]

Is there some way to get the background image visible on the associated sites?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem a while ago too. I ended up raising a support ticket with Microsoft, and they told me that this is known and that hub sites don't currently support pushing backgrounds.

If you really wanted to do this you would have to apply the background manually to each site.

Comment: I was afraid of that answer, I have tried to find a script to apply background image but there is not so much info about that, Does anyone know if its possible? Or have an working code for it?